# Is it possible to make first letter big and make the rest of the text align around it

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to make first letter big and make the rest of the text align around it like on this Picture?[image]

If yes then how?

Comment: Won't a flowplayout panel render like this...? Not sure if it will wrap tho, maybe worth testing...

Comment: @LouisvanTonder `FlowLayoutPanel` is winforms.  `WrapPanel` would be the corresponding tool here.

Comment: @J... but it would not do the job.

Comment: @J... I tried RichTextBox it dosent work

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this quite happily using `FlowDocument` elements.

```
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Margin="0,0,204,0">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Figure HorizontalAnchor="ColumnLeft" Margin="0">
                    <Paragraph BreakColumnBefore="False" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="55">
                        <Run FontSize="70">T</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </Figure><Run>his is a paragraph of text are it should wrap the first letter. Wheren there is lots of text, multiple lines will appear besides our larger character.</Run>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run>This is the second paragraph in our body of text.</Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

[image]

You can read more about `FlowDocument` [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I played with the lineheight and linestackingstrategy but couldn't figure out how to remove the whitespace from the bottom of the font. Lineheight is not proportional to the font height so you need to alter both in tandem if you need to.

Comment: It dosen't look like its supported by Windows 8 xaml

and the properties: "BreakColumnBefore="False" BreakPageBefore="False" KeepWithNext="True" KeepTogether="True""
aren't supported

Comment: @AlexanderYW those properties are artifacts of my experimentation. Feel free to remove them.

Comment: Well if I remove them then I got the same as I did before were the text doesn't align around the letter